# How to implement redirect login with Java + AngularJS

Tags: rest-api, oauth2, authentication, java

For example site: aside.io, when we click Sandbox login, it takes you to test.salesforce.com and then when you enter your user name and password it authenticates and redirects to the aside.io with the classes and other files from that org?

While creating my own apex editor I was reading the USerName and password+security token via properties file. But now I have to implement the login screen same as what aside.io does.

What resources should I read to achieve this? Does aside.io store the username and password? Or how do they download and the files and deploy the files ? I suspect it through cookies? Is there any example i can follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [OAuth 2.0 User-Agent Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm&type=5). Using this mechanism, you set up a [Connected App](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=connected_app_overview.htm&type=5), which sets an icon, name, and "scope" (permissions) for your application. Your application, in turn, directs the user's browser to a particular URL to proceed with the Salesforce login. *Salesforce* provides the login screen and handles the username/password/two-factor/verification etc for you. At the end of the flow, Salesforce redirects to your callback URL and provides you with a session ID (called an Access Token). The only thing you store is the Access Token. The username/password/security token/etc are unknown to your application, which is a lot safer for you and your users. You do get an [Identity URL](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_using_openid.htm&type=5) if you need to identify a user in an external database, and there are API calls to get the user's details (e.g. name and email, but notably *not* the user's password).

Comment: So that means when I set up a Connected App will i get some unique Id, as we get when developing Social login via gmail. I better try. Thanks

Comment: So I have successfully implemented oauth logic, but I had to create a connected app in my org and then get the client_id and have a onclick on my JS : as `window.open('https://' + orgType + '.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=3MVG9d8..z.******&redirect_uri=https://4260e7c7.ngrok.io/html/apexEditor.html&state=' + (orgType === 'test' ? 'a' : 'b'), '_self');`

But what if a new org wants to use my editor, do I have to create this connected app in each and every org?

Comment: Also I got this return `https://4260e7c7.ngrok.io/html/apexEditor.html?code=*%3D%3D&state=b`

Comment: @RahulJain No. Connected apps don't need to be installed in each org. It happens automatically on first use. The "code" you get needs to be redeemed for a token before you can use it. Try using the User-Client flow instead.

Comment: I got the access token from the code, i saved it in HttpServletRequest cookies, but say I need to get all the classes in my org? How can I login only via this access token to get or deploy classes to my org? Previously I was using PartnerConnection and used to create ConnectorConfig, in which I was using username and password, which is not safe, but If i place ConnectorConfig `setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+accessToken[0].getValue());` and fire a login request it fails with error `Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.`

Comment: @RahulJain You don't need to log in; an access token means you're *already* logged in. Just call the appropriate REST endpoints as necessary.

Comment: Ok yes understood, Basically now while creating connector config we have to pass access token to Session Id and Service endpoint as instance_url.

`ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
        config.setSessionId(accessToken);
        config.setServiceEndpoint(instanceUrl);`

Comment: @RahulJain Yes, that's correct.